# Writing value to file

Tags: php

Struggling!

The following code is supposed to take the value from a form, add that value to a value which it reads from data.php then rewrite the new value to data.php

```
<?php
//get form value
$add_value = $_GET["txt_InterimDonationSubtotal"]; //Will always be a number (10.00, for example)
echo $add_value;

// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "../assets/files/donation_total/data.php";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

//Say what you got!
echo $contents;

//Get the numbers outta there :)  (Will be some kind of number '100.00' for example)
$value = substr($contents, 13);
$value_cleaned = substr($value, 0, -4);

//Add the two numbers together
$new_total = $value_cleaned + $add_value;

//Rewrite the values back to the file
$new_data_content = "<?php $$data=$new_total;?>";
file_put_contents('../assets/files/donation_total/data.php', $new_data_content);
?>
```

The output does not echo anything, as it should (just for now, I'll remove it when i know it's working), it does write *something* back to data.php, but not what it should. The following is what I get in data.php when I open it in Sublime:

```
<?php $=0;?>
```

As you can see, the name of the variable 'data' is not being saved in the file, and it is not adding the values together! Why?!

Desired output is along the lines of:

```
<?php $data='125.85';?>
```

Thanks to the help of people answering I've got this far:

```
<?php
//get form value
$add_value = $_GET["txt_InterimDonationSubtotal"]; //Will always be a number (10.00, for example)
echo $add_value;

// get contents of a file into a string
$contents = file_get_contents('../assets/files/donation_total/data.php');

//Say what you got!
echo "contents:".$contents;

//Get the numbers outta there :)  (Will be some kind of number '100.00' for example)
$value = substr($contents, 13);
$value_cleaned = substr($value, 0, -4);

//Add the two numbers together
$new_total = $value_cleaned + $add_value;
echo "newtotal:".$new_total;

//Rewrite the values back to the file
$new_data_content = "<?php $data='".$new_total."';?>";
file_put_contents('../assets/files/donation_total/data.php', $new_data_content);
?>
```

This now naming the variable just fine, but the contents are not being read and echoed (why?!) and the values are not being added together, because it's not doing a great job of getting the file contents to being with I'm guessing.

Comment: If you use **file_put_contents** to write why not to use **file_get_contents** to read file ?

Comment: Will that matter Scony? This code doesn't need to be clean, it just needs to work.

Comment: Ofc. not. Relax, it's just hint. This is why I wrote it in comment. Btw. If you expect more than one user, consider **LOCK_EX** flag in **file_put_contents** or you will loose some data because of overriding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because strings with double quotes have variables within them magically interpreted. When PHP sees the string `"<?php $$data=$new_total;?>"` it says where are the variables `$data` and `$new_total` then evaluates those variables within the string. $new_total is a defined variable and its value is written to the string but $data is not so it's value is not.

You could however write your string where it is not evaluated at all using single quotes like this `'<?php $$data=$new_total;?>'`. However then all the text would be written literally to your file.

What I think you want is to concat the string with the value. `'<?php $data="' . $new_total . '";?>'`

Did you try serialization?

```
<?php
    $add_value = $_POST["txt_InterimDonationSubtotal"];
    $contents = file_get_contents("../assets/files/donation_total/data.txt");
    if($contents) {
        $contents = unserialize($contents);
    } else {
        $contents = 0;
    }
    $contents += $add_value;
    file_put_contents('../assets/files/donation_total/data.txt', serialize($contents));
?>
```

Comment: Yes, the code I am not using is this: $new_data_content = '<?php $data='.$new_total.';?>';

But the value to be saved is being output as 0, which is not the resultant output where the form input is 15.00

Comment: When `value_cleaned` and `add_value` are echo'ed is there a value? Try echoing `new_total`, is there also a value?

Comment: i wouldn't recommend this but you could just `eval` the contents of the file.

Comment: Contents outputs nothing, new_total outputs 0 :(

Comment: I would recommend getting the contents using `file_get_contents` since it does what you want in 1 line of code.

Comment: It changes data.php to <?php $data=0;?> instead of <?php $data='15.00';?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49773/discussion-between-mike-ashfield-and-logan-murphy)